# Why are aligned arguments compiling properly, but getting crashed at runtime?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have this code in two VS2010 projects:

```
__declspec(align(16)) struct S {
    int a;
};

void f(S v) {}
```

It shouldn't compile, because you cannot pass aligned arguments to functions (unless you pass them by reference); and one project *does* reject it, as I expected. But the other project compiles it O.K., and then it crashes at runtime.

My question is: why is this ever allowed to compile?

I've looked through all the compiler options, and I can't find anything relevant.

Comment: No repro.  Both the RTM and SP1 releases of Visual C++ 2010 emit the expected diagnostic: "`error C2719: 'v': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned`," with the default compilation options.  Please post a complete repro that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I could not post the whole project with many files. My question was, can this error be disabled somehow.

Comment: No, errors cannot be disabled.

Comment: @EmilKirichev: try recompiling the entire solution. Likely the other project doesn't know it needs to change.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I'm aware of that :). This is not a traditional 'error', it's more like compiler implementation related and an issue similar to this has sparkled alot of disscusions in the MSDN forums and other places.

Comment: @EmilKirichev This question has been flagged as "too localized". Given the comments above and the fact that this is more than 1 month old, I'll assume that this is not actually a problem of the compiler, but of the fact that not all parts of your project were compiled consistently, so I'll vote to close as too localized. Do tell if you think this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that you don't have a macro called 'align' defined anywhere?  If not then place

```
#undef align
```

immediately above the code and recompile.  If it fails then you have that macro defined somewhere.